# Render to a texture, then render result to screen in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, textures

I need to render an OpenGL scene to a texture in order to then manipulate that texture in a shader. I've solved this by using Framebuffer Objects, which I think I understand fairly well by now. At many points in my effect pipeline, I need to render a fullscreen quad and texture it with the dynamically rendered texture, which is where my problem is.

This is what my scene looks like: https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thomak/planet.jpg

I render this to a texture and map that texture to a fullscreen quad. However, the resulting image is distorted in this way: https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thomak/planettexture.jpg

Here is the code that renders the quad and sets the texture coordinates:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
glVertex3i(-1, -1, -1);    
glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
glVertex3i( 1, -1, -1); 
glTexCoord2i(1, 1);   
glVertex3i( 1,  1, -1); 
glTexCoord2i(1, 0);   
glVertex3i(-1,  1, -1);

glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
```

And the shader code is here:

```
sampler2D BlitSamp = sampler_state
{
  MinFilter = LINEAR;
  MagFilter = LINEAR;
  MipFilter = LINEAR;
  AddressU = Clamp;
  AddressV = Clamp;
};

float4 AlphaClearPS(float2 texcoords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
  return float4(tex2D(BlitSamp, texcoords).rgb, 1.0f);
}
```

Where BlitSamp is the texture I rendered to and then passed to the shader. What could be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your tex-coords are off. Your code, my comments:

```
glTexCoord2i(0, 0);     //Bottom-Left
glVertex3i(-1, -1, -1); //Bottom-Left    

glTexCoord2i(0, 1);     //Top-Left
glVertex3i( 1, -1, -1); //Bottom-Right??? 

glTexCoord2i(1, 1);     //Top-Right
glVertex3i( 1,  1, -1); //Top-Right

glTexCoord2i(1, 0);     //Bottom-Right
glVertex3i(-1,  1, -1); //Bottom-Left??
```

Comment: Thanks, you're spot on! I'm basically porting a Direct3D application to OpenGL and wasn't aware of the fact that they disagree on the origin of UV space... I know it's top-left in Direct3D, so is it bottom-left in OpenGL?

Comment: They are typically bottom-left in OpenGL, yes. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code to render the quad looks fine so that would point to a mismatch in the size of the quad and the size of the viewport.

Could you have swapped the width and height when you created the render texture, by any chance ?